# Python 2.7(sqlite3) to SQL Oracle, Safe Variables (Prevent SQL Injection)

Tags: sql, oracle, python-2.7, variables

```
if instance = "PROD":
     dblink = ('db9_pub',)
elif instance = "BETA":
     dblink = ('dbq9_pub',)
elif instance = "TEST"
     dblink = ('dbt9_pub',)

#Pre-defined SQL Statements    

table1_select = ("""select * from example.table1@? """)
table1_insert = ("""insert into example.table1@? (SQL_SELECT_STATEMNT) """)

conn1 = cx_Oracle.connect(logininfo)
cursor1 = conn1.cursor()

cursor1.execute(table1_select,(dblink))
cursor1.execute(table1_insert,(dblink))
```

So I'm about to start writing a lot of python scripts that will need to pass variables into the SQL statements. Some will be safer like the posted script, some will need to be guarded from SQL injection attacks. I would like to understand the difference between the use of the various variable techniques and which ones are most appropriate.

** %s, '%s', ?, :1  All seem the same to me. What is the appropriate way to do this for safe code? ** I think I've worked this out, I need ?s due to the API I'm using.

BTW, the posted script is throwing an error: illegal variable name/number, so i'm obviously not understanding even the basic application of this.

=============
Edit:
I found this information on a page (http://bobby-tables.com/python) that actually helps some. It helps me work out which version of placeholder to use, but doesn't inform me of how to guard from SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your above code you can't use a variable in the query string for the specified DBLink. Bind variables are only allowed in places where an expression are allowed, and they will never be interpreted as a database object (table name, column name, function name, etc). However, since you appear to be in complete control of the DBLink through your chained if statements it would be safe (in this instance) to concatenate the DBLink into your query strings:

```
if instance = "PROD":
     dblink = ('db9_pub',)
elif instance = "BETA":
     dblink = ('dbq9_pub',)
elif instance = "TEST"
     dblink = ('dbt9_pub',)

#Pre-defined SQL Statements    

table1_select = ("""select * from example.table1@%s """%(dblink))
table1_insert = ("""insert into example.table1@%s (SQL_SELECT_STATEMNT) """%(dblink))

conn1 = cx_Oracle.connect(logininfo)
cursor1 = conn1.cursor()

cursor1.execute(table1_select)
cursor1.execute(table1_insert)
```